Why does Double.CompareTo() use "==" internally?
One should not use == to compare real numbers, every C# developer knows that.
Then why the Double.CompareTo method, from the framework, is implemented this way for checking equality?
public int CompareTo(double value)
{
    if (m_value < value) return -1;
    if (m_value > value) return 1;
    if (m_value == value) return 0; // <= here
    
    // At least one of the values is NaN.
    if (IsNaN(m_value))
        return IsNaN(value) ? 0 : -1;
    else
        return 1;
}

This is the code's source.

What other thing were you expecting it might use?

I couldn't find any reference in the documentation but believe that  CompareTo must fulfill the usual properties of an ordering relation, I.e. reflexivity, transitivity and anti-symmetry. Especially x.CompareTo(x) must be 0. Transitivity excludes fuzzy equality (at least if any pair of numbers compares as non-equal).

@paradise,   FWIW, if (IsNaN(m_value)) return IsNaN(value) ? 0 : -1; else return 1; is risky code if used in a qsort() fashion.  To flesh out the details, the larger context is needed.  IMO, to keep a sort algorithm consistent, when a NAN is involved, make all NAN a super +inf (or -inf).  When comparing 2 NANs, compare bit patterns.

@paradise Using a difference tolerance prevents a total ordering and renders using compare worthless in a sort algorithm.

@chux Why bother to compare bit patterns?  Why not just (contrary to IEEE754) declare all NaNs as equal?

@SteveSummit "declare all NaNs as equal" is another valid approach.  Code usually does that with +0.0 and -0.0 too.  A list of zeros, like a list of NANs, do not sort when the compare treats them as equal.  It simple depends on the goal in these corner cases.  With C23, decimal FP will also see this issue as many finite values can have multiple encodings. So something like if a > b return 1, if a < b return -1, return bit_pattern compare is the idea for a total sort.

@chux: if (IsNaN(m_value)) return IsNaN(value) ? 0 : -1; else return 1; is not risky; it makes all NaNs equal to each other and less than all non-NaNs. (A NaN on the left is less than a non-NaN on the right, and a non-NaN on the left is greater than a NaN on the right.) It satisfies the requirements for a comparison function used for ordering.

@EricPostpischil Agree, with some remaining concerns: Depending on coding goals, I find it more common to want all the NAN on the right so the portion of array used may be easily shortened and NANs ignored.  Also the if (m_value < value) return -1; and at least 1 object NAN, is unclear to me: is that well defined in C#?  In C,  if it follows IEEE, it is  well defined, yet C need not follow IEEE.  IOWs, ifNAN tests more portable before the math tests - yet of course that is usually slower.


One should not use == to compare real numbers, every C# developer knows that.

Perhaps some C# developers believe that, probably not every C# developer, but nobody can know it because it is not true. There are circumstances where you should use ==, and there are circumstances where you should not. If you want to sort floating-point numbers or use a comparison to insert them into a data structure such as a tree, you need an ordering on them, and comparisons with <, ==, and > are fine for that, with allowances for NaNs as the code shown makes.
If you are trying to test whether the results of two floating-point computations produce equal results, that is a different problem. It is actually an instance of a general problem: Floating-point arithmetic approximates real-number arithmetic, and therefore floating-point results are approximations of what you would get using real arithmetic. So it is not just ==; any floating-point operation can produce a result different from real arithmetic. You could add and multiply numbers that would produce 37 with real arithmetic but that produce 31.25 with floating-point arithmetic. Maybe that is fine for a particular application, maybe it is not. Often, if the operations involved have modest derivatives with respect to the operands, the rounding errors in the results stay modest.
However, if you compute operations that have large derivatives, then early small rounding errors can become large errors in results. So, for example, computing the tangent near π/2 is a problem, dividing by numbers near zero is a problem, and subtracting two nearly equal numbers is a problem. And == has an “infinite” derivative where its operands are equal. So the rule is not “avoid ==”; it is “avoid computations in regions with large derivatives or discontinuities.”


One should not use == to compare real numbers, every C# developer knows that.

Well, no, not quite.  It's more like:

"One should not use == to compare real numbers, every developer has heard that."

And it's true: comparing floating-point numbers for exact equality is very often a really bad idea.
But that does not mean that if you find yourself tempted to compare for exact equality, what you should do is to compare for approximate equality instead.  Often, what you want to do is adjust your thinking so that you don't have to compare for equality — approximate or exact — at all.  (And the reason is that properly comparing for approximate equality is really hard — in fact it can be just as bad an idea as comparing for exact equality, because of the possibility of doing it wrong.)
The reason that Double.CompareTo uses == internally is that it's basically the only thing it can use.  And if there's a rule that says "don't use == to compare floating-point numbers for exact equality", that rule basically also says "Don't use Double.CompareTo to compare floating-point numbers for exact equality, either."  One's just as bad as the other in that regard.
It would not be possible or reasonable for Double.CompareTo() to implement an approximate equality comparison internally, because it's impossible to define a single, general-purpose approximate-equality test that's suitable for every application.  It turns out that every application probably needs to make its own, application-specific definition of what "approximate equality" means.  Sometimes you want to compare against an absolute threshold like 0.00001; sometimes you want to use a threshold that's relative to the magnitude of the numbers being compared.  And there's no one threshold that's right for every problem — in fact, for an arbitrary algorithm, choosing just the right comparison threshold is basically an unsolved problem.


One should not use == to compare real numbers, every C# developer knows that.

I assume you mean that floating point values should usually be compared with some tolerance, due to the inherent issue of floating point representation (which is summarized in this post: Is floating-point math broken?).

Then why the Double.CompareTo method, from the framework, is implemented this way for checking equality?

There is really no other implementation that can make sense in general, because the tolerance for comparing values is dependant on your context. There's no one tolerance that fits all cases.
Also in some cases it does make sense to use == for comparing floating point values:
E.g. if you have:
double d1 = ...;      // initialized with some non-zero value
double d2 = 0;
if (<some_condition>) {
    d2 = d1;
}

Then if you want to check whether d2 was assigned to d1 using == is perfectly valid.
The explamantion above applies to < and > as well.
Bottom line:
Instead of using CompareTo you should compare with some tolerance that fits your conext of floating point calculations (unless you have a case like e.g. the assignment as mentioned above).
